# How to update column for database according to similar data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database as below:

```
id     name     url
1     France    NULL
2      USA      NULL
...
```

The `url` is about the links to resources in my cloud server. It is just like this:

```
http://myserver.com/France/something
http://myserver.com/USA/something
```

I have created the table for a long time. Now my colleague just finished uploading all of resources to the cloud server so I just received all of the urls.

What I need to do is to update the column `url`.

My colleague gave me a csv file as below:

```
http://myserver.com/France/something,http://myserver.com/USA/something
```

Is there some easy way (such as some sql script) to update my table? I'm sure that each url contains the value of the column `name`. For example, `http://myserver.com/USA/something` contains the value `USA`, which is `select name from mytable where id = 2`.

Comment: You really need regex? If the data sample are those you showed above you can use a like clause in the where on you update statemet

Comment: @e.arbitrio Well, I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Can you explain what is on the csv file exactly? Is it a ONE line csv?

Comment: @tafia  it's all of urls. It could be reformed into multiple lines if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with sample data like yours and this code works

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (url VARCHAR(45));
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'urls.csv'  INTO TABLE temp_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' IGNORE 1 LINES (url);
UPDATE cities JOIN temp_table on temp_table.url LIKE CONCAT('%', cities.name ,'%') SET cities.url = temp_table.url;cities
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table;
```

Good luck

Comment: I just edited my answer grouping all the code. I play the sql now on sample data and it works perfectly. Let me know

Comment: Oh I know. Your code works well. But sometimes I have some special cases. Such as I'm trying to match `abc%20def` with `abc def`.

Comment: If you have the only whitespaces special case you can try to replace %20 char and then TRIM the whitespaces and compare, otherwise you have to use a regexp

Comment: I'm totally a newbie on SQL. Could you please show me how to use TRIM or regexp?

Comment: I got it. `UPDATE cities JOIN temp_table on temp_table.url LIKE CONCAT('%', replace(cities.name, ' ', '%20') ,'%') SET cities.url = temp_table.url;`  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First split the urls then update urls using like.

function to split the values:

```
            create FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitValues] (@StringArray NVARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter NVARCHAR(10)) 
            RETURNS @ResultedValues table ( ResultValue nvarchar(max) ) 
            AS 
            BEGIN
              declare @string nvarchar(max)
              set @string = @StringArray
              WHILE (CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String)>0)
               BEGIN 
                INSERT INTO @ResultedValues (ResultValue) VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String,1,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String)-1))))
                SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String,   CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String)+LEN(@Delimiter),LEN(@String))
               END 
            INSERT INTO @ResultedValues (ResultValue ) VALUES ( LTRIM(RTRIM(@String)))
            RETURN
            END
```

update statement:

```
            update t
            set url = fn.ResultValue
            from mytable t
            join [dbo].[SplitValues] ('http://myserver.com/France/something,http://myserver.com/USA/something') ,',') fn
                on fn.url like '%'+t.name+'%'
```